# How to use while loop with GUI I tried but could not get the right solution

Tags: python-3.x, user-interface, tkinter, while-loop, infinite-loop

How could I use an Infinite while loop along with Tkinter?
I tried to make a GUI for a game but the while loop would not work along with Tkinter
I also used the after method but could not get the desired output.

I tried using it, Every time I execute it either the GUI freezes or the GUI does not appear at all.

```
def game():
   global currentRoom
   global rooms
   global inventory
   global monster
   global health
   While True:
    showStatus()                  

    move.clear()
    while move == []:  
      move_entry=Entry(window,width=25)           
      move_entry.pack() 
      window.update()
      submit_button=Button(window,text="Submit",command=lambda:submit(move_entry.get()))
      submit_button.pack() 
      time.sleep(10)

    if move[0]=="shoot":  
      if "monster"in rooms[currentRoom] and move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]['monster'] and "shotgun" in inventory :
          del rooms[currentRoom]['monster']
          message_label=Label(window,text=f"you killed the {move[1]}")
          message_label.pack()
          rooms[currentRoom].update({"monster":"dead"},)
        
      else:
          message_label=Label(window,text="you cannot attack " )
          message_label.pack()
          

      
    if move[0]=="use":
      
      
      if "bandage" in inventory and move[1]== "bandage":
          heal=40
          health=min(100,health+heal)
          inventory.remove("bandage")
          message_label=Label(window,text="you recovered 40 health (max 100)")
          message_label.pack()

      elif "key" in inventory and move[1]== "key" and "golden_crown" in inventory and currentRoom=="Garden":     
         message_label=Label(window,text="you escape with the loot, you retire in style, you win!!  ")
         message_label.pack()
         break
              
          
      elif "key" in inventory and move[1]== "key" in inventory and currentRoom=="Garden":
         message_label=Label(window,text="you escape the house but die a pauper, you lose ")
         message_label.pack()
         break

      

      else:
          message_label=Label(window,text="can't use that")
          message_label.pack()

      
    
    if move[0] == 'go':
      if move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]:
          currentRoom = rooms[currentRoom][move[1]]
      else:
          message_label=Label(window,text=r"You can\'t go that way!")
          message_label.pack()

    if move[0] == 'get' :
          
      if 'item' in rooms[currentRoom] and move[1] in rooms[currentRoom]['item']:
          inventory += [move[1]]
          message_label=Label(window,text=f"move[1] got!")
          message_label.pack()
          del rooms[currentRoom]['item']
     
      else:
          message_label=Label(window,text=r"Can\'t get that")
          message_label.pack()
        
    if 'zombie' in rooms[currentRoom]['monster']:
      message_label=Label(window,text="A zombie attack you !!!")
      message_label.pack()
      health=health-30

    if 'ghoul' in rooms[currentRoom]['monster']:
      message_label=Label(window,text='A ghoul attack you !!!')
      message_label.pack()
      health=health-20

    if health<0:
      message_label=Label(window,text="you are dead")
      message_label.pack()
```